# Python/ Django- How to change what information is displayed in a template?

Tags: python, html, django, view

I am working on a project that has been written in Python/ Django, and on one of the webpages, there is a table displaying some information about objects in a database.

The table is displayed in a 'tabbed content' elements, and each tab displays a different table. The information displayed in each table varies (i.e. the table has different columns) depending on the type of objects that it is displaying.

I want to remove one of the columns from one table in this 'tabbed content' element.

The `view` that returns the URL for this webpage is defined with:

```
def report_ccis(request, project_id):
    """ CCI items styled for pdf """
    print "report_ccis() called in costing.views (1463) "
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    budget = get_current_budget(project_id)

    cci_total_exc = budget.cci_total_exc_vat_final
    cci_grouped_items = budget.cci_items.all().order_by('project_room', 'name')

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'cci_total_exc': cci_total_exc,
        'cci_grouped_items': cci_grouped_items,
        'webview': 1,
    }

    try: context['current_budget'] = project.budget_versions.get(current_marker=1) #For option name/date on top of pdfs
    except ObjectDoesNotExist: pass

    if request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd':
        print "request.GET('stage') == 'pd' "
        """ Render post deposit homepage """
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)
        print "'render_to_sting() called with parameter: costing/report2_ccis.html "
        context['active_tab'] = '4'
        print "render() called with parameter: costing/reports_post_deposit.html "
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
    else:
        print "request.GET('stage') != 'pd' "
        """ Render pre deposit homepage """
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
        print "'render_to_sting() called with parameter: costing/report_ccis.html "
        context['active_tab'] = '5'
        print "render() called with parameter: costing/reports_pre_deposit.html "
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

The `view` either returns 'reports_post_deposit.html', or 'reports_pre_deposit.html' depending on the type of `request` that is made, and on both pages, this currently displays a table in the 'tabbed content' area, with column headings for 'Items', 'Initial Sum', 'Latest Sum' & 'Notes'.

What I want to do, is remove the 'Latest Sum' column from the table on the 'reports_pre_deposit.html' page, but I'm not sure how to do this in Python/ Django- would I do it by changing the Django HTML file, or by changing the Python `view`?

The `report_ccis.html` file that's being passed to `render_to_string()` is:

```
{% extends "pdf2_base.html" %} 
{% load money_handling %}
{% block web_content %}

{% block content_overview %}
{% endblock content_overview %}
{% block content_construction %}
{% endblock content_construction %}
{% block content_schedule_of_works %}
{% endblock content_schedule_of_works %}
{% block content_report_by_class %}
{% endblock content_report_by_class %}
{% block content_ccis %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis %}

{% block content_payment_schedule %}
{% endblock content_payment_schedule %}
{% block agreed_variations %}
{% endblock agreed_variations %}
{% block agreed_variations_client %}
{% endblock agreed_variations_client %}
{% block agreed_variations_construction %}
{% endblock agreed_variations_construction %}
{% block unagreed_variations %}
{% endblock unagreed_variations %}
{% endblock web_content %}
```

**Edit**
I amended the HTML to include the new block, as suggested:

```
{% extends "pdf2_base.html" %} {#ERF(02/12/2016 @ 1150) Change from 'pdf_base.html - to ensure it displays all relevant variables. ' #}
{% load money_handling %}
{% block web_content %}

{% block content_overview %}
{% endblock content_overview %}
{% block content_construction %}
{% endblock content_construction %}
{% block content_schedule_of_works %}
{% endblock content_schedule_of_works %}
{% block content_report_by_class %}
{% endblock content_report_by_class %}
{% block content_ccis %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis %}
{# Set the block to content_ccis_pre_deposit) #}
{% block content_ccis_pre_deposit %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis_pre_deposit %}
{# Add details that are displayed in report2_ccis.html here too #}
{% block content_payment_schedule %}
{% endblock content_payment_schedule %}
{% block agreed_variations %}
{% endblock agreed_variations %}
{% block agreed_variations_client %}
{% endblock agreed_variations_client %}
{% block agreed_variations_construction %}
{% endblock agreed_variations_construction %}
{% block unagreed_variations %}
{% endblock unagreed_variations %}
{% endblock web_content %}
```

But when I now try to display the page in the browser, I get an error message that says:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /costing/5547/report/ccis/

and highlights the line:

```
context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
```

as the issue... I'm not sure why this is causing a problem?

**End Edit**

The column that I want to remove will be displayed by the lines:

```
{% block content_ccis %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis %}
```

but this is also what will be displaying the rest of the columns- which I want to keep...

The `reports_pre_deposit.html` file itself is defined with:

```
{% extends "costing/reports_tabbed.html" %}
{% load staticfiles utilities %}

{% block title2 %}
    | Pre-deposit reports
{% endblock title2 %}

{% block page_title %}
    <a id="topbar-shortcuts" data-view-url="{% url 'hub:open_sidebar' %}?app={{app.name}}&p={{project.id}}&po=1">
        <span class="m-l-md">Reports</span> <img class="icon open text-sm m-l-md" src="{% static 'img/down-lt.png' %}" >
    </a>
    <div id="topbar-results" class="{{app.color}}" style="display:none;"></div>
{% endblock page_title %}


{% block tabs %}
    {% with 'Overview, Construction budget, Schedule of works, Client choice items'|listify as tabs %}
        {% for tab_name in tabs %}
            {% with forloop.counter as tab %}
                {% if not tab == active_tab|add:0 %}<a class="tab" href="{% url 'costing:report_tabbed' project.id %}?tab={{tab}}">{% else %}<a class="active tab">{% endif %}{{tab_name}}</a>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock tabs %}
```

How would I remove the column from the line `{{block.super}}`...? Or would I need to remove it from the `view` that is rendering this HTML, or from the HTML file itself?

I tried looking into the parameters that are being passed to the `context` variable in the `report_ccis(..)` view, but none of these appear to set which columns are displayed in the table.

Can anyone point out how/ where I would change what columns are displayed?

**Edit**

The `block` from `pdf2_base.html` that the HTML files `extend`, where the tables are displayed is:

```
{% block content_ccis %}
    {% if not webview %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="plain-link" href="{% url 'costing:home' project.id %}">Client Choice Items - please refer to 'Budget Explained'   </a>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: right;">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="project-name">{{project.project_name|upper}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    {% endif %}

    <table class="pdf-report left">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="width:400px;">Items</th>
                <th>Initial sum (£)</th>
                <th>Latest sum (£)</th>
                <th colspan="3">Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in cci_grouped_items %}
                {% ifchanged item.project_room %}
                    <tr class="sub-summary">
                            <td>{{item.project_room}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endifchanged %}
                <tr style="padding:0.1cm;">
                    <td  colspan="3" style="width:400px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.initial_cost|money}}</td>
                    <td {% if item.final_cost == item.initial_cost %}style="color:blue;"{% endif %}>{{item.final_cost|money}}</td>
                    <td colspan="3">{{item.notes|xor}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            <tr class="end-table-section">
                <td colspan="8"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="last-row">
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td>Total excluding VAT</td>
                <td>{{cci_total_exc|money:'£'}}</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>To help you understand the rationale behind these items, please refer to booklet 'Budget explained'. </p>
{% endblock content_ccis %}
```

If I comment the 'Latest Sum' table heading with `<!--th>Latest sum (£)</th-->`, this obviously removes the heading from the table, but I'm not sure how I then remove the values that are displayed in that column- and it ends up just moving the 'Notes' column heading one to the left, so that this is now above the 'Latest Sum' values, and the 'Notes' column no longer has a heading.

Is there a way I can make this conditional on whether the table is displaying `pre-deposit` or `post-deposit` figures, or would I need to write a separate `HTML` block for each case?

**Edit**

The `(% block content_ccis %}` section now looks like this:

```
{% block content_ccis %}
    {% if not webview %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="plain-link" href="{% url 'costing:home' project.id %}">Client Choice Items - please refer to 'Budget Explained'   </a>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: right;">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="project-name">{{project.project_name|upper}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    {% endif %}

    <table class="pdf-report left">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="width:400px;">Items</th>
                <th>Initial sum (£)</th>
                {% if post_deposit %}
                <th>Latest sum (£)</th>
                {% endif %}
                <th colspan="3">Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in cci_grouped_items %}
                {% ifchanged item.project_room %}
                    <tr class="sub-summary">
                            <td>{{item.project_room}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endifchanged %}
                <tr style="padding:0.1cm;">
                    <td  colspan="3" style="width:400px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.initial_cost|money}}</td>
                    {% if post_deposit %}
                        <td {% if item.final_cost == item.initial_cost %}style="color:blue;"{% endif %}>{{item.final_cost|money}}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                    <td colspan="3">{{item.notes|xor}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            <tr class="end-table-section">
                <td colspan="8"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="last-row">
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td>Total excluding VAT</td>
                {% if post_deposit %}
                    <td>{{cci_total_exc|money:'£'}}</td>
                {% endif %}
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>To help you understand the rationale behind these items, please refer to booklet 'Budget explained'. </p>
{% endblock content_ccis %}
```

The updated view is:

```
def report_ccis(request, project_id):
    """ CCI items styled for pdf """
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    budget = get_current_budget(project_id)

    cci_total_exc = budget.cci_total_exc_vat_final
    cci_grouped_items = budget.cci_items.all().order_by('project_room', 'name')

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'cci_total_exc': cci_total_exc,
        'cci_grouped_items': cci_grouped_items,
        'webview': 1,
    }

    try: context['current_budget'] = project.budget_versions.get(current_marker=1) #For option name/date on top of pdfs
    except ObjectDoesNotExist: pass

    if request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd':
        """ Render post deposit homepage """

        context['post_deposit'] = True

        print "request.GET('stage') == 'pd' "
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)
        context['active_tab'] = '4'
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
    else:
        """ Render pre deposit homepage """
        print "request.GET('stage') != 'pd' "
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
        context['post_deposit'] = True
        context['active_tab'] = '5'
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{block.super}}` means block content of parent template.
Because parent template in your case is "pdf2_base.html" I suppose you can find required column in "pdf2_base.html" template.

**Update**
If you need to vary which block to show you can add context variable 'post_deposit':

```
if request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd':
    print "request.GET('stage') == 'pd' "
    """ Render post deposit homepage """
    context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)
    print "'render_to_sting() called with parameter: costing/report2_ccis.html "
    context['active_tab'] = '4'
    print "render() called with parameter: costing/reports_post_deposit.html "
    return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
else:
    print "request.GET('stage') != 'pd' "
    """ Render pre deposit homepage """
    context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
    context['post_deposit'] = True
    print "'render_to_sting() called with parameter: costing/report_ccis.html "
    context['active_tab'] = '5'
    print "render() called with parameter: costing/reports_pre_deposit.html "
    return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

In template `pdf2_base.html` check post_deposit value and display required column:

```
...
{% if post_deposit %}
    <th>Latest sum (£)</th>
{% endif %}
...
{% if post_deposit %}
    <td {% if item.final_cost == item.initial_cost %}style="color:blue;"{% endif %}>{{item.final_cost|money}}</td> 
{% endif %}
...
{% if post_deposit %}
    <td>{{cci_total_exc|money:'£'}}</td>
{% endif %}
...
```

Comment: Ah- brilliant, thanks. I had a look in that file- and can see where the column heading & data is coming from- but the problem I have if I comment/ remove it from there, is that the data is then not displayed for the `reports_post_deposit.html` file. Is there a way that I can make this information being displayed conditional on whether I am viewing `pre-deposit` reports or `post-deposit` reports? If not, I guess I would need to copy & paste this `block` with a different name, and use one for `pre-deposit` & the other for `post-deposit`? I'll add the HTML for this table to my OP.

Comment: @someone you can add some variable to the context is_predeposit and then check ot in template: {% if is_predeposit %}

Comment: Or of corse you can simply add another block.

Comment: I think doing it with a variable would probably be tidier- and hopefully mean less issues with any future changes made- where would I define this?

Comment: @someone2088 context always defined in view. But if i inderstood problem correctly you have only one view for all tables. So you cannot just pass some variable into context for some specific case. So based on what I can see you only have to add new block.

Comment: I tried adding a new `block`, but when I now try to display this page in the browser, I get a `templateSyntaxError` at `costing/id/report/ccis`, which says it's complaining about the line: `context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context) `, i.e. the HTML file that I added the `block` to... why would it have an issue with this? I'll update my OP to show how I've added the `block`.

Comment: I've amended my OP to show how I tried adding the new `block`, and the issue this is now giving me...

Comment: @someone2088 try to comment also this `<td {% if item.final_cost == item.initial_cost %}style="color:blue;"{% endif %}>{{item.final_cost|money}}</td>` and this `<td>{{cci_total_exc|money:'£'}}</td>`

Comment: It seems the reason the page was broken was because I had renamed the opening tag to `{% block content_ccis_pre_deposit %}`, but had forgotten to rename the closing tag, so it was still `{% endblock content_ccis %}`. However, after fixing this, although my page now displays again- it is displaying two tables at the same time, i.e. one with the 'Latest Sum' column, and just below it, one without the 'Latest Sum' column. The other data in both tables is identical.

Comment: @someone2088 well if you dont need first one, just remove following `{% block content_ccis %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis %}` from "report_ccis.html"

Comment: I did that, but for some reason, the table is still displayed twice in the way I described in my previous comment...

Comment: @someone2088 try this: add following `{% block content_ccis %}
{% endblock content_ccis %}` empty content_ccis should solve the issue.

Comment: I did that, and while it has removed the second table from the page, it has also removed the `Latest Sum` column from the first table- so now whether I display `post-deposit` or `pre-deposit`, I only see the `Initial Sum` column. What I'm aiming for, is when displaying the `post-deposit` information, both `Initial Sum` and `Latest Sum` columns should be displayed, but when displaying `pre-deposit` information, only `Initial Sum` should be displayed

Comment: Thanks for the update- I'm just wondering whether the code for the template would work with this though- as it seems to be missing `{% endblock %}` tags for the `{% block content_ccis_pre_deposit %}`...? I gave it a go, but got an error message displayed in the browser. I've also tried it after adding in the `{% endblock %}` tags, but then get a `templateSyntaxError` that says: `'block' tag with name 'content_ccis' appears more than once`...

Comment: @someone2088 now I see it was not good idea to create new block. Sorry for complexity. Can you try one more thing? Just comment new block. And in the block `content_ccis` make changes from my answer.

Comment: Ok, so I've done that- but I get the same issue with the column heading `Latest Sum` being removed from the table, but all of the data from that column still being displayed, and the `Notes` column heading being shifted over to take its place...

Comment: And the column heading for `Latest Sum` is also no longer displayed when actually viewing `post_deposit` information...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129822/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-someone2088).

Answer (score 0):

you can send a context variable to decide whether to render block.super or not

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? This `block` is what is displaying everything on the `CCIs` tab of the tabbed content on the web page- there are four columns displayed there at the moment- I still want to display three of them, and only remove the one. If I don't render `block.super`, then everything on that tab disappears...

Comment: sorry, maybe you can have two different block in your parent template  render the block based on the variable you sent in context.                   {% block content_ccis %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis %}                                                                   {% block content_ccis2 %}
    {{block.super}} // this display without that last column
{% endblock content_ccis2 %}